# XCode 4.2 has problems debugging on my attached ipod touch with 3.1.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have XCode 4.2 Build 4C199.

I downloaded the ios support files for ios 3.x devices since Im testing
on my ipod touch 1st gen with ios 3.1.2

No matter what project I create, I try to test my app from xcode
on the attached ipod (is recognized) but:

when I press run it compiles with no errors but it just stops
running saying: "Finished running ProjectName"

In simulators it works just fine :-)

No errors in output...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

1) Add armv6 architecture in your Target build options and check that your deployment target is iOS 3.1.2.

[image: screenshot]

2) Remove value of "armv7" from "Required device capabilities" (UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities) in your Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

xCode 4.2 builds the application to run on devices with architecture armv7.
Means it will only work with iPhone 3gs or greater, iPod touch 3rd generation or greater(Sorry, i am not sure) and iPad 1&2.

In Target->Build Settings, add Armv6 to the architectures.
After adding it will be like this

```
ARCHS = armv6 $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
```

Also add Armv6 in valid Architectures
After adding it will be like this

```
VALID_ARCHS = armv6 armv7
```

Then finally in -info.plist delete the entry

```
Required device capabilities - armv7
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert device
2. exit xcode
3. and restart xcode